# epstopdf error: /undefined in uageLevel:

Tags: matlab, epstopdf

I try to run:

```
C:\Users\Oleg\Desktop>epstopdf.exe test5-reference.eps
```

and I get just an a blank .pdf with the following:

```
Error: /undefined in uageLevel:
Operand stack:

Execution stack:
%interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   
%stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1
%stopped_push   1926   1   3   
%oparray_pop   1925   1   3   
%oparray_pop   --nostringval--   1909   1   3   
%oparray_pop   1803   1   3   
%oparray_pop   --nostringval--   
%errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2
%stopped_push   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1169/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:81/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: No such file or directory
MiKTeX GPL Ghostscript 9.05: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
epstopdf.exe: Invalid argument
```

No idea what might be wrong. I am on Win7 64bit.

[Link to test5-reference.eps](https://www.dropbox.com/s/r63qli1miuan6do/test5-reference.eps?dl=0)

### EDIT

Matlab R214b is used to create the .eps with the call:

```
print(gcf, '-depsc', filename)
```

which uses settings specified in `printjob()`. Specifically:

```
pj.PostScriptTightBBox = 1; %True if want to have a tight BoundingBox
```

Basically, it creates in the .eps the line:

```
%%BoundingBox: (atend)
```

However, epstopdf specifically says:

```
The case of "%%BoundingBox: (atend)" when input is not seekable (e.g., from a pipe) is not supported.
```

Now, the question is, why is the input not seekable, or is it a **bug** in epstopdf?

Also, would be interesting to check how previous versions of Matlab create the .eps with the same call.

## EDIT 2

The issue as identified by Christian Zietz of the epstopdf team:

> I investigated a little further: It seems that the problem occurs only
>   with MikTeX epstopdf and only if two things come together:
>   "%%BoundingBox: (atend)" in the header of the EPS file and Unix-style
>   line endings, meaning only LF and not CR+LF as it is customary in Windows.

I filed a bug report to Miktex.

Comment: I just converted your test file on linux with `epstopdf` script -- there were no errors

Comment: Why no export directly to `pdf` from *MatLab*?

Comment: I run `epstopdf` in *Windows* and i got the same problem. I converted with *Acrobat Distiller* and no problem

Comment: @skpblack Cannot export directly in .pdf, not my choice. I do manage to open the file with ghostscript.

Comment: @skpblack: MATLAB has some cropping issues with PDF export, that's the reason for EPS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into this as well on Windows. I used two solutions, the first one being portable and preferred.

**Solution 1.** Just read the eps file as text inside Matlab and replace any new lines `\n` by carriage returns + new lines `\r\n`. To make this portable, just use fwrite with the 'text' flag:

```
f = 'myplot.eps';
eps = fileread(f);
fd = fopen(f, 'wt');
fwrite(fd, eps);
fclose(fd);
system(['epstopdf ' f]);
```

Note the `wt` instead of just `w` in fopen(). This tells fopen() to write in text mode, which will replace any `\n` or `\r\n\` with whatever the current OS is using, i.e. `\r\n` on Windows, `\n` on Linux etc.

**Solution 2.** The other, less portable way (and prone to font embedding issues) is to call Ghostscript directly to convert the .eps to .pdf and then `pdfcrop` (from Miktex) to crop to the bounding box for no white margins. You need to install Ghostscript for this, obviously.

```
gswin32c -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o myplot.pdf myplot.eps
pdfcrop --hires --margins 0.25 myplot.pdf
```

This will produce `mygraph-crop.pdf` which you can use. You could also use the eps2pdf.pl script from [the Xpdf binaries](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/download.html) for Windows, but as far as I remember, that script also calls gswin32c. It may pass better/more complete options to gswin32c though (I haven't tried it). Note that you will (most probably) get warnings about font substitutions. The pdf should look fine, I haven't run into any visual issues. If it doesn't look fine then fixing those is a different animal (you'd have to either point Ghostscript to search more font paths probably via the -sFONTPATH= switch, or edit the font mapping file).

I just use Solution 1.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I am using R2014b as well. 
Saving a figure in matlab with the commandline using the `'print -depsc'` or `'saveas('*.eps')` commands results in the same eps-code as mentioned by previous posters, having the following Bounding Box properties in the *.eps file:

```
%!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0
%%Creator: (MATLAB, The Mathworks, Inc. Version 8.4.0.150421 \(R2014b\). Operating System: Windows 7)
%%Title: filename.eps
%%CreationDate: 2015-01-12T18:05:47
%%Pages: (atend)
%%BoundingBox: (atend)
%%LanguageLevel: 3
%%EndComments
```

But when I use the matlab gui to save the exact same figure as a *.eps i get a different behaviour. Now i get a *.eps file which is working with epstopdf in miktex:

```
%!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0
%%Creator: (MATLAB, The Mathworks, Inc. Version 8.4.0.150421 \(R2014b\). Operating System: Windows 7)
%%Title: path/filename.eps
%%CreationDate: 2015-01-12T18:07:15
%%Pages: (atend)
%%BoundingBox: 0 0 403 302
%%LanguageLevel: 2
%%EndComments
```

Update:
when i use the hgexport function, i get a *.eps file which is working with epstopdf as well.

```
matlab code:
epsfig = hgexport('factorystyle');
epsfig.Format = 'eps';
hgexport(gcf,'filename',epsfig,'Format','eps')

eps-file:
%!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0
%%Creator: (MATLAB, The Mathworks, Inc. Version 8.4.0.150421 \(R2014b\). Operating System: Windows 7)
%%Title: filename.eps
%%CreationDate: 2015-01-12T18:02:36
%%Pages: (atend)
%%BoundingBox: 0 0 403 302
%%LanguageLevel: 2
%%EndComments
```

I found this solution in the mathworks community:http://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/159509-eps-export-problems-in-r2014b

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Perhaps you should elaborate on your answer and show us a screen shot?